# Silent Install Powershell Popwindow

Tags: .net, powershell, frameworks

I am trying both using exe and msi to install .NET 4.8 but still the pop up window comes up. I tried all the syntax what has been provided here for silent install but none works.

Start-Process -Wait -ArgumentList "/Silent" -Passthru -Filepath "=============\filename.exe"
Start-Process -Wait -ArgumentList "/Silent" -Passthru -Filepath '=============\filename.exe'
Start-Process -Wait  -Filepath "=============\filename.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /V /qn" -Passthru

Anything I try nothing works. I have seen several users have had problems in the past and why is it something it is not resolvable? Any suggestions? I am sure it should be possible to install through PS or batch file. If I try using the batch file I get a WINDOW popup for msiexec.exe

Any suggestions it is simple install of .NET file from the network location.

Comment: `msiexec /i YourMsiFile.msi /qn`

Comment: this should help: [.NET silent install](https://silentinstallhq.com/microsoft-net-framework-silent-install-master-list/)